# Replace part of a URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I've found lots of articles around matching the URL and then replacing a certain part of just that particular URL...

BUT!

The website I need to change has around 25,000 URLs with the below string I need to replace! What I'm trying to do is:

mysite.com/p/product_name_10011029

And replace: /p/

with

mysite.com/product/product_name_10011029

Again, there's 25,000 or so different pages that have /p/ in the URL so it can't match just one URL

Comment: I get the feeling that you have a rewrite rule somewhere that you could change instead maybe? Or are all those URLs generated and stored in the HTML or Database or something?

Comment: I'm trying to run an A/B test and we've built out a new product page on a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace`:

```
url = url.replace('/p/', '/product/');
```

If you have string, then you can use `regex`:

```
myHtml.replace(/mysite\.com\/(p)\/.*/gi, 'product');
```

Answer (score 0):

You pinned javascript and jquery as tags:
use replace with regex

exampe:

```
string.replace(/mysite\.com\/(.*?)\/(.*)/, 'mysite.com/product/\2');
```

please provide more informations, so we can help better

Comment: That doesn't appear to be working. What more information do you need? I'm trying to run an A/B test an "expose" the test pages (/product/) via replacing /p/ with /product/

I've been specific enough I thought with the original question?

Comment: in which context do you execute the replace? could you provide any examples to show us your code? _That doesn't appear to be working_ what is the error, or the unexpected result? in my test-cases from your description it worked for me