# How to use jQuery replace() after a certain index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The url being replaced looks like this:

```
/profile/something/
```

with `something` being dynamic but `profile` should always be in the url. I tried `'/\w+/g'` as the first argument in replace(), but it did this instead:

```
/hello123/hello123/
```

instead of:

```
/profile/hello123/
```

Does anyone know how I can use the replace() only after a certain index of the url string? Or maybe replace every character except the first instance of `profile`?

Comment: There is no `replace` function in jQuery. Perhaps you're talking about the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function in JavaScript? There are many questions about replacing parts of the URL. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/q/30457053/215552?

Comment: you can use `string.slice(x)` where `x` is the number of characters you wish to skip

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/4025635/215552

Comment: Thanks guys string.slice(x) works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @Adjit - str.slice(x) works well here and is the most simple.

```
new = $('#view_posts').attr('href').slice(9);

$('#view_posts').attr('href', $('#view_posts').attr('href').replace(new, data.username));
```

or

```
new = $('#view_posts').attr('href').slice(0, 9);

$('#view_posts').attr('href', new + data.username);
```

Comment: This will replace the terminating slash, as well. It's just grabbing everything after 9 characters and replacing it, which seems very inefficient. Instead you could `slice(0,9)` and append to that with no replace needed.

Comment: True that does seem better, i've changed it to my 2nd edit. Thanks.